# InfoPath 2013 Document Cannot Be Opened in SharePoint 2007 Workflow in InfoPath 2013

Tags: workflow, infopath

I have an InfoPath 2007 document that is submitted and creates a SharePoint workflow. This works fine in InfoPath 2010 and SharePoint 2007. When upgrading to InfoPath 2013, the document submits without issue, but cannot be opened as part of an approval workflow.

The error received is: "InfoPath cannot open a new form. One or more required custom controls in this form cannot be created." I've seen similar errors to this using web search, but none that were triggered by InfoPath 2013.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**

I tried deleting one control at a time and republishing as has been suggested. I also tried creating a new form in InfoPath 2013 with the bare minimum of controls. The newly created form contains  a Text Box, a Drop Down Menu, a date picker, and has one Data Connection based on the dropdown menu. Still no luck.

http://easycaptures.com/9337613601

**

The newly created form contains  a Text Box, a Drop Down Menu, a date picker, and has one Data Connection based on the dropdown menu.